# Samsung Galaxy tab 10 does not start up

Tags: charging, boot, reboot

My tablet won't start. With the USB cable connected I can start my tablet using the "power & volume" trick.

When in prompt menue for various reboot options it says in yellow text

> Can't access tp /system/csc/NSE/system

When I chose "reboot system now" and it starts up as fresh new but when I disconnect the cable there's total blackness and it's impossible to start up. The charger icon says 100%.

How can I get the tablet starting normally?